# Special (magic) methods in Python

Tags: python

What are all the special (magic) methods in Python? The `__xxx__` methods, that is.

I'm often looking for a way to override something which I know is possible to do through one of these methods, but I'm having a hard time to find how since as far as I can tell there is no definitive list of these methods, PLUS their names are not really Google friendly. So I think having a list of those here on SO would be a good idea.

Comment: These are often called "magic methods." That might help with google.

Comment: "Magic"?  Where'd you get that?  The Python documentation calls them "special method names".  I've never seen them called "magic".  Where did you see that?

Comment: @S.Lott No? Haven't you [readen the docs](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.1.html?highlight=magic#pep-207-rich-comparisons)? Haven't you readen [the guide](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) to them?

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed. The question is useful and constructive and the answer is supported by reference. There is nothing to debate or argue for this question. I don't see this violating any of the rules in help center.

Comment: Here is the excellent link which explain python's magic method in detail [link](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)

Comment: @ketorin: The reason why good questions like this get closed is because it is fun for people who have been granted shiny new powers to exercise them.

Comment: Couldn't find any documentation for these, but this gives a good overview: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Comment: @OCDev then why haven't people reopened it?

Comment: @tox123 - It remains closed because the mental barrier is higher to go against an established precedent than it is to set a precedent where one had not been established yet. Can you tell us why it makes sense for this question to have been closed?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

At the python level, most of them are documented in the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames). At the C level, you can find it under the [object protocol](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html) section (strictly speaking, you only have a subset here, though).

Comment: +1: Every single one, clearly listed.  Google "Python Special Method Names" and you get 700,000 reponses starting with section 3. of the Language Reference.

Comment: Another [helpful link](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)