# who can tell me what can call the built-in functions in next code 

Tags: python

i know some of this,ex.

`__mod__` will be call  /

`__eq__`will be call == > and <

but i don't know all.

```
    def __nonzero__(self):
        # an image is "true" if it contains at least one non-zero pixel
        return self.im.getbbox() is not None
    def __abs__(self):
        return self.apply("abs", self)
    def __pos__(self):
        return self
    def __neg__(self):
        return self.apply("neg", self)

    # binary operators
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.apply("add", self, other)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.apply("add", other, self)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.apply("sub", self, other)
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.apply("sub", other, self)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.apply("mul", self, other)
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.apply("mul", other, self)
    def __div__(self, other):
        return self.apply("div", self, other)
    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return self.apply("div", other, self)
    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self.apply("mod", self, other)
    def __rmod__(self, other):
        return self.apply("mod", other, self)
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return self.apply("pow", self, other)
    def __rpow__(self, other):
        return self.apply("pow", other, self)

    # bitwise
    def __invert__(self):
        return self.apply("invert", self)
    def __and__(self, other):
        return self.apply("and", self, other)
    def __rand__(self, other):
        return self.apply("and", other, self)
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.apply("or", self, other)
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return self.apply("or", other, self)
    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self.apply("xor", self, other)
    def __rxor__(self, other):
        return self.apply("xor", other, self)
    def __lshift__(self, other):
        return self.apply("lshift", self, other)
    def __rshift__(self, other):
        return self.apply("rshift", self, other)

    # logical
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.apply("eq", self, other)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.apply("ne", self, other)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.apply("lt", self, other)
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.apply("le", self, other)
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.apply("gt", self, other)
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.apply("ge", self, other)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special (magic) methods in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Section 3.4](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) of the Python Language Reference covers the magic methods.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Special Method Names](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) section in the reference manual, including [Basic Customization](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) and [Emulating Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Answer (score 1):

`__mod__` is called for `%`, **not** for `/` as you state:

```
>>> class x(int):
...   def __mod__(self, y):
...     print '__mod__(%s, %s)' % (self, y)
...     return int.__mod__(self, y)
... 
>>> a = x(23)
>>> a / 4
5
>>> a % 4
__mod__(23, 4)
3
>>>
```

Make and use similar toy classes to clarify any doubt you may have about a special method, if any are left after you read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).