# Python : What all implicit __xyz__ methods exists inside a default python class?

Tags: oop, class, object, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Special (magic) methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python)
>   [who can tell me what can call the built-in functions in next code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983199/who-can-tell-me-what-can-call-the-built-in-functions-in-next-code)

I have being using python and every now and then I discover an implicit class method of the type `__xyz__` which holds a special meaning and is over-rided for custom usages.

For example:

```
class some_class:
    def __init__(self):
        # Everyone knows about this. [ Constructor ]
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        # string representation of object I suppose.
        pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        # Unicode representation of object I guess
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        # Similar to destructor
        pass
```

**These all available over-ridables are useful, but I am not able to find how to refer them or find a documentation of all such available `__xyz__` types available in a python class.**

What all `__xyz__` stuff is available and how do you use them to make your life easy ?

What is the pythonic `zen` behind this ?
What are the analogous counterparts in other languages such as C++ ?

Comment: Interesting.. can you explain what is desired with this ? I want to understand the zen behind this thing.

Comment: Any of the methods are available for any user-created class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible names are described in [section 3.4](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) of the Python language specification.

Comment: Interesting.. can you explain what is desired with this ? I want to understand the zen behind this thing.