# Easy way of overriding default methods in custom Python classes?

Tags: python, class, methods, overriding

I have a class called Cell:

```
class Cell:

    def __init__(self, value, color, size):
        self._value = value
        self._color = color
        self._size = size

    # and other methods...
```

`Cell._value` will store a string, integer, etc. (whatever I am using that object for). I want all default methods that would normally use the "value" of an object to use `<Cell object>._value` so that I can do:

```
>>> c1 = Cell(7, "blue", (5,10))
>>> c2 = Cell(8, "red", (10, 12))
>>> print c1 + c2
15

>>> c3 = Cell(["ab", "cd"], "yellow", (50, 50))
>>> print len(c3), c3
2 ['ab', 'cd']

# etc.
```

I could override all the default methods:

```
class Cell:

    def __init__(self, value, color, size):
        # ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._value[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._value)

    # etc.
```

...but is there an easier way?

Comment: why does an integer, `self._value`, have the ability to get indexed by a key? And have you ever tried taking the length of an integer? Also, this should probably not be cocmmunity wiki: nobody get's points for answering that way and we love us some points here at SO.

Comment: -1: this should not be a wiki.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth `self._value` could hold any data type so I want to have all possible methods available.

Comment: Sorry about setting this "community wiki". I didn't realize that disabled points and was irreversible. Now I know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for an easy way to delegate an object's method to a property of that object?

You can avoid some of the repetitiveness by defining a decorator:

```
def delegate(method, prop):
    def decorate(cls):
        setattr(cls, method,
            lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
                getattr(getattr(self, prop), method)(*args, **kwargs))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

You can then apply the decorator for each method you want delegated:

```
@delegate('__len__', '_content')
@delegate('__getitem__', '_content')
class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self._content = content

spam = MyList([1,2,3,4,5])

len(spam) # prints "5"

spam[0] # prints "1"
```

You could probably simplify it further by modifying the decorator to take multiple method names as argument.

If you want your class to act as a full wrapper, you could probably override the class's `__getattr__` method to check the wrapped object before failing. That would emulate the behaviour of subclasses without actual inheritance.

Comment: I think overriding `__getattr__` is closer to what I'm looking for but I see the value in the decorator option as well. Now I just need to understand the different between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the `__add__` method in order to get the `c1 + c2` behavior you want.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python/1090635#1090635) for info on what they all are.