# Override multiple methods with a wrapper (Python 3)

Tags: python, class, inheritance, overriding, wrapper

In my effort to subclass `float` and override multiple numeric operations with a wrapper, I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721607) and tried the following:

```
def naturalize(*methods):
  def decorate(cls):
    for method in methods:
      method = '__' + method + '__'
      original = getattr(cls.__base__, method)
      setattr(cls, method, lambda self, *args, **kwargs: cls(original(self, *args, **kwargs)))
    return cls
  return decorate

@naturalize('add', 'sub', 'mul')
class P(float):
  pass

print('Test result:', P(.1) + .2, P(.1) - .2, P(.1) * .2)
# Test result: 0.020000000000000004 0.020000000000000004 0.020000000000000004
```

This didn't work: `__add__`, `__sub__` and `__mul__` were all working like `__mul__`. So I looked at [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721607) and tried:

```
def naturalize(*methods):
  def decorate(cls):
    def native(method):
      original = getattr(cls.__base__, method)
      return lambda self, *args, **kwargs: cls(original(self, *args, **kwargs))
    for method in methods:
      method = '__' + method + '__'
      setattr(cls, method, native(method))
    return cls
  return decorate

@naturalize('add', 'sub', 'mul')
class P(float):
  pass

print('Test result:', P(.1) + .2, P(.1) - .2, P(.1) * .2)
#Test result: 0.30000000000000004 -0.1 0.020000000000000004
```

Now, that did work. But I'm still not sure what exactly went wrong with my first approach. Can anyone please explain to me how exactly `__add__`, `__sub__` and `__mul__` ended up all working like `__mul__`?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, all `lambda`s have the same scope which means that when `method` was changed, it was reflected in all the `lambda`s. Nesting it in a function as in your second example creates a new scope per call, which isolates the `lambda`s from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this debugging version of `naturalize`:

```
def naturalize(*methods):
    def decorate(cls):
        for method in methods:
            method = '__' + method + '__'
            original = getattr(cls.__base__, method)
            setattr(cls, method,
                    lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
                    (cls(original(self, *args, **kwargs)), original.__name__))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

You'll get output like this:

```
Test result: (0.020000000000000004, '__mul__') (0.020000000000000004, '__mul__') (0.020000000000000004, '__mul__')
```

So we see that `original` is always equal to `__mul__` by the time the decorated method is called. Indeed, when the decorated method is called,

```
cls(original(self, *args, **kwargs))
```

is evaluated. Since `original` is a local variable in `decorate`, it retains the *last* value it had after the `for-loop` ended. So `original` always evaluates to `__mul__`.

The correct version,

```
def naturalize(*methods):
    def decorate(cls):
        def native(method):
            original = getattr(cls.__base__, method)
            return lambda self, *args, **kwargs: cls(original(self, *args, **kwargs))
        for method in methods:
            method = '__' + method + '__'
            setattr(cls, method, native(method))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

avoids this problem by defining `original` as a local variable in `native`. Now, by *calling* `native(method)` for each `method`, inside `native` original is bound once to each desired original value.