# Python: __cmp__ and __str__?

Tags: python, methods

What happens if you don't define your own for methods `__cmp__` and `__str__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If no __cmp__(), __eq__() or __ne__() operation is defined, class
>   instances are compared by object identity (“address”).

For more detailed info: refer to [object.__cmp__(self, other) in Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__). And you can get further references [Special (magic) methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python).

Answer (score 6):

With no `__str__` defined, you will get the default one with the memory address e.g. `<__main__.A object at 0x165aa90>`.

If no `__cmp__()` operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity i.e. memory address ([docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)).

Examples:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> str(a)
'<__main__.A object at 0x7fcb1df8acd0>'
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x7fcb1df8acd0'
>>> a < b
False
>>> a > b
True
>>> id(a), id(b)
(140510357925072, 140510357925008)
```