# Confusion to figure out between attribute or method in Python

Tags: python, methods, module, attributes

According to this following thread

[How to differentiate between classes, functions, and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757724/how-to-differentiate-between-classes-functions-and-methods?rq=1)

`snake_case` for functions and methods to determine if it's specific type.

I was looking at `string` module and I did `print(dir(string))` and got all these

[`Formatter`, `Template`, `_ChainMap`, `_TemplateMetaclass`, `__all__`, `__builtins__`, `__cached__`, `__doc__`, `__file__`, `__loader__`, `__name__`, `__package__`, `__spec__`, `_re`, `_sentinel_dict`, `_string`, `ascii_letters`, `ascii_lowercase`, `ascii_uppercase`, `capwords`, `digits`, `hexdigits`, `octdigits`, `printable`, `punctuation`, `whitespace`]

I was just trying to get a range of alphabets using `string.ascii_lowercase`
but is not `ascii_lowercase` a `method` according to the link mentioned above? and a `method` needs to be called as `ascii_lowercase()`. but it is not working , is their a clear way to distinguish what is what?

I am confused here , someone please help me out.

**Edit 1:**
Just to be more clear on my question, an `instance` does usually have `attributes` and `methods` and even `method` is considered as an `attribute` to an `instance` , so this is where confusion arises for me.

Comment: As the documentation states, `dir` returns a list of symbols defined in the argument's symbol table (directory).  This includes both attributes and methods.  A simple test would show you that removing the parentheses returns the specified alphabet.

Comment: @prune you just mentioned what I already told about 'dir()' that it gives attributes and methods but did not actually answer my question.

Comment: Your question is how to get the alphabet.  I did answer that.  Your question says that you're confused about how to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily tell the difference by checking the type of the symbol.  For instance:

```
>>> type(str.isupper)
<class 'method_descriptor'>
>>> type(string.ascii_lowercase)
<class 'str'>
```

Perhaps less direct, you read the package documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`string.ascii_lowercase` holds the string value:

```
>>> import string

>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

To know the type of attribute, you can use [**`type()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) on [**`getattr()`**](http://%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). Here's example to show type of all values returned by `dir(string)`:

```
for x in dir(string):
    print("'{}' - {}".format(x, type(getattr(string, x))))

# which print the output as:
#   'Formatter' - <type 'type'>
#   'Template' - <class 'string._TemplateMetaclass'>
#   '_TemplateMetaclass' - <type 'type'>
#   '__builtins__' - <type 'dict'>
#   '__doc__' - <type 'str'>
#   '__file__' - <type 'str'>
# .... so on ....
```