# decorator __lt__ and others - why use these and how do they work?

Tags: python

I stumpled into a problem of understanding the decorators. Compared to the code below, what is the use of the `__lt__(self, number)` method compared to the `less_than(self, number)` method?
Is there any difference between the two methods and how they handle the arguments?

```
 class Sort:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __lt__(self, number):
        return self.number < number

    def less_than(self, number):
        return self.number < number
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with decorators. `__lt__` is as special method Python will call when comparing two objects with `<`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special (magic) methods in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python)

Comment: This has nothing to do with decorators (which are something completely different). The rest of the question *is* pretty valid though.

Answer (score 2):

The two functions, `__lt__()` and `less_than()` do the same thing. However, there is a big difference:
When you use the "<" operator, the function `__lt__` is called internally by python. So, you can do this

```
x = Sort(5)
y = Sort(10)
print(x < y)
```

The comparison `x < y` calls `x.__lt__(y)`, and so it returns `true`. In this way you can change the behavior of built in operators for the specific class you have created. See "operator overloading" and "python magic methods" for more details

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn Pieters said this has nothing to do with decorators.

```
s1 = Sort(1)
s2 = Sort(2)

if s1 < s2:
    print 'Yes'

if s1.less_than(2):
    print 'Yes'
```

See the difference?
In the first if you compare to objects of type Sort.
In the second if you invoke a method from instance s1 of type Sort.