# Which classes do Python intrinsic methods belong to?

Tags: python, object

1- In Python, which classes do the methods that begin and end with two underscores  (eg: `__gt__`, `__eq__`, ...) belong to?

2- Which classes/modules are imported implicitly for all Python programs?

3- Is there a general way to get the class name for any given method?

Comment: 1. Whichever classes define them

Comment: Take a look at [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html). FWIW, these methods are sometimes known as [dunder methods](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200605/dunder.html).

Comment: 2. The `__builtins__` is module is always present.

Comment: Use bacticks (\`) to format code so that you don't have to write _ _ gt _ _. For example: \`__gt__\` comes out as `__gt__`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special (magic) methods in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dir() to find out

```
for k in dir(__builtins__):
    print str(k) + " : :\n" + str(dir(eval(k))) + "\n\n"
    try:
        a = input("type enter for next:")
    except(SyntaxError):
        continue
```

you can use ctrl+c to end the programs excecuteion and of course jsut call dir() on any particular type you are interested in.

Comment: print(int.__gt__(2,10))  -> False      print(int.__gt(20,10)) -> True     . Using your answer, I've found the __gt__ method we use like 2>10. Thanks. Indeed, many classes use their own implementations of methods like __add__, __gt__, etc. But for numbers, I could guess that the right class is "int" .

Comment: @onur how this comment is even remotely related to the answer by kpie?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Using this answer, I could see a list of classes and their methods. And among those methods, I could find `__gt__` method belongs to "int". I've tried to use `int.__gt__` and it worked correctly, and by my comment above, I wanted to show this. As I'm using Pyhton 3, I've modifed the print statement.

Comment: Glad I could help.